# Delete file/folder and wipe it

Tags: windows, security, wipe

Is there a simple way (in Windows 7 or higher) to **delete a file or folder and wipe it**? (all data filled with zero bytes is enough for me).

Either with GUI:

```
Right click on file > Contextual menu > "Wipe and delete"  (vs. the usual "Delete")
```

or with command-line:

```
wipedel C:\Users\Myself\AppData\Local
```

(this would wipe and delete the folder and its subdirectories)

Comment: Not sure about context menu-based, but Piriform Recuva has an option to permanently remove data (as opposed to recovering it). "Sometimes you want a file gone for good. Recuva’s secure overwrite feature uses industry- and military-standard deletion techniques to make sure your files stay erased." https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: `fsutil file [setzerodata] offset=offset length=length PathName` [Fsutil documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx) can be used to fill a file with zeros.

Comment: @spikey_richie Would be cool if Recuva provided a context menu, working also for folders (that would wipe also the subdirs). Any idea someone?